# How to pass a dynamically created struct as non-pointer object in Go

Tags: pointers, reflection, go

I'm trying to dynamically pass parameters to a URL route handler function. I thought it would be possible to use the reflection package to convert a map of values from the URL to the function that has one parameter that happens to be an anonymous struct. I've gotten as far as creating the struct to pass to the handler function but it ends up being a pointer to the struct. If I change the handler function's signature to expect a pointer the created struct ends up being a pointer to a pointer, I think. At any rate, here's the code (the panic follows):

Link: http://play.golang.org/p/vt_wNY1f08

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)


func mapToStruct(obj interface{}, mapping map[string]string) error {
    dataStruct := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(obj))

    if dataStruct.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return errors.New("expected a pointer to a struct")
    }

    for key, data := range mapping {
        structField := dataStruct.FieldByName(key)

        if !structField.CanSet() {
            fmt.Println("Can't set")
            continue
        }

        var v interface{}

        switch structField.Type().Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice:
            v = data
        case reflect.String:
            v = string(data)
        case reflect.Bool:
            v = string(data) == "1"
        case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int16, reflect.Int32:
            x, err := strconv.Atoi(string(data))
            if err != nil {
                return errors.New("arg " + key + " as int: " + err.Error())
            }
            v = x
        case reflect.Int64:
            x, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data), 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return errors.New("arg " + key + " as int: " + err.Error())
            }
            v = x
        case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
            x, err := strconv.ParseFloat(string(data), 64)
            if err != nil {
                return errors.New("arg " + key + " as float64: " + err.Error())
            }
            v = x
        case reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint16, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
            x, err := strconv.ParseUint(string(data), 10, 64)
            if err != nil {
                return errors.New("arg " + key + " as int: " + err.Error())
            }
            v = x
        default:
            return errors.New("unsupported type in Scan: " + reflect.TypeOf(v).String())
        }

        structField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    }
    return nil
}

type RouteHandler struct {
    Handler interface{}
}

func (h RouteHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(h.Handler)

    handlerArgs := reflect.New(t.In(0)).Interface()

    if err := mapToStruct(handlerArgs, mux.Vars(req)); err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error converting params"))
    }

    f := reflect.ValueOf(h.Handler)

    args := []reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(handlerArgs)}
    f.Call(args)

    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World")
}


type App struct {
    Router mux.Router
}

func (app *App) Run(bind string, port int) {
    bind_to := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", bind, port)
    http.Handle("/", &app.Router)
    http.ListenAndServe(bind_to, &app.Router)
}

func (app *App) Route(pat string, h interface{}) {
    app.Router.Handle(pat, RouteHandler{Handler:h})
}


func home(args struct{Category string}) {
    fmt.Println("home", args.Category)  
}


func main() {
    app := &App{}
    app.Route("/products/{Category}", home)
    app.Run("0.0.0.0", 8080)
}
```

Panic:

```
2013/03/28 18:48:43 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:51204: reflect: Call using *struct { Category string } as type struct { Category string }
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:589 (0x3fb66)
    _func_004: buf.Write(debug.Stack())
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1443 (0x11cdb)
    panic: reflect·call(d->fn, d->args, d->siz);
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:428 (0x484ba)
    Value.call: panic("reflect: " + method + " using " + xt.String() + " as type " + targ.String())
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/reflect/value.go:334 (0x47c3a)
    Value.Call: return v.call("Call", in)
/Users/matt/Workspaces/Go/src/pants/pants.go:86 (0x2f36)
    RouteHandler.ServeHTTP: f.Call(args)
/Users/matt/Workspaces/Go/src/pants/pants.go:1 (0x347c)
    (*RouteHandler).ServeHTTP: package main
/Users/matt/Workspaces/Go/src/github.com/gorilla/mux/mux.go:86 (0x5a699)
    com/gorilla/mux.(*Router).ServeHTTP: handler.ServeHTTP(w, req)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:669 (0x337b6)
    (*conn).serve: handler.ServeHTTP(w, w.req)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:271 (0xfde1)
    goexit: runtime·goexit(void)
```

Comment: This is probably an abuse of reflection in Go. By doing this, you lose one of Go's most important features - it's type safety. It's hard to get what you're trying to do, but this looks like you really only need a map of http.Handlers.

Comment: Can't quite see what you are trying to do ... but whatever it is it looks like a bad idea. Why does your `Handler` need to be an `interface{}` rather than a func type? Why can't your handler just accept the `map`? ... I would suguest trying to pretend the reflect package doesn't exist for this problem.

Comment: Abuse? I'd say thats subjective. Bad idea? Subjective as well. The tools are there to achieve what I'm trying to do so whatever. My goal, regardless of your opinion, is to develop an easy to use API for handling URL's with parameters that are part of the URL. Similar to how the Python framework Flask does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call Elem() on your reflect.Value object.

Quoting from [The Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/2011/09/laws-of-reflection.html) article:

> To get to what p points to, we call the Elem method of Value, which indirects through the pointer

Comment: I actually read that entire article. Sometimes you just need someone that knows better to tell you what you're doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @MattW: Could you point me to a modified, working code example of this? :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that `reflect.New()` creates a pointer to a value of the type you pass it.  So on the following line:

```
handlerArgs := reflect.New(t.In(0)).Interface()
```

`handlerArgs` will be a pointer to a struct of type `t.In(0)`.  You will need to dereference that pointer to have a value suitable to pass to the function.

I'd suggest the following:

1. Make `hanlerArgs` a `*reflect.Value` for the actual struct value:

   ```
   handlerArgs := reflect.New(t.In(0)).Elem()
   ```
2. Make `mapToStruct` take such a `*reflect.Value` instead of an `interface{}` holding a pointer to a struct (it is a helper for your reflection code, after all).
3. Use `handlerArgs` directly as one of the function arguments for the `Call() invocation.

Comment: why dynamically allocate a value just to dereference it? instead of `reflect.New(t.In(0)).Elem()`, they should just do `reflect.Zero(t.In(0))`

Comment: @newacct What you say is true, however the important difference between both is that the return value of [`reflect.Zero()` is not addressable nor settable](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero), whereas the result of `reflect.New(Type).Elem()` is an addressable and settable `reflect.Value` . I know this is an old discussion/comment but google doesn't care and keep sending people here, so i guessed it could be useful ;-)